# Short way to assign values from an array to multiple textboxes on a form?

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

I have an array I am using and I need to assign all the values from it to 81 textboxes. The textboxes are named oneOne, oneTwo, oneThree, and so on all the way up to nineNine in a 9x9 square grid. I would like the textboxes to be assigned values from a two-dimensional array with the index matching the textbox name. My question is: How can I complete this action using a nested loop? I understand how I can change 1 to "one" but I don't know how I would actually assign the values.

Comment: Why not keep a Dictionary of your textboxes along with the values to be assigned ?

Comment: I am not using a dictionary because I would like to do this with a loop is all, it would be much less typing.

Comment: If you keep a dictionary of ID/value, you could then assign each textboxes with the ID the value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

i have something similar in VB....
here is how i did it...
what i named the textboxes as  textbox_1_1;textbox_1_2;textbox_2_1 and so on

```
for a = 0 to array.count
   for b = 0 to array(a).count
      dim txtbx as textbox = findcontrol("textbox_" & a.tosrting& "_" & b.tostrong)
      txtbx.text = array(a)(b)
   next b
next a
```

hope this example helps.. you may need to modify it to fit into your program and use the form1.findcontrol and so on...

NOTE: findcontrol is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

First, inside your constructor after calling InitializeComponent():

```
Textbox[,] textboxes = new Textbox[9,9];

// Code to populate the array.  81 assignment statements.
```

Then you'd loop over the value array & lookup the Textbox from the array:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 9; j++ ) {
        textboxes[ i, j ].Text = array[ i, j ];
     }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I wanted to go about it, I just didn't know how to. There is one problem though, visual studio gives me the error "The name 'textboxes' does not exist in the current context" - What do I do now?

Comment: If the code that's populating the `TextXBox[]` is in the constructor, but the code that does the look up is in another method, make the `Textbox[]` a property of the form.  That way the variable will live as long as the form does and you can access it from any method you write.